# Manually upgrade a web app from the .NET Framework 3.5 to .NET v4.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, frameworks, web-config, iis-8

I have a old web application targeting .Net framework 3.5 on Visual Studio 2013 with IIS express which should be IIS 8.0 so I want to upgrade the target framework to the version 4.0.

According to msdn [website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd483478(v=vs.100).aspx)

> "If you do not use Visual Studio to perform the upgrade automatically,
>
> you must manually edit the Web.config file
>
> and must manually associate the application in IIS with the .NET
>   Framework version 4."

I modified my web.config according to the mentionned steps 
then in order to associate the application with the .NET Framework 4 in IIS 8.0 I executed on cmd this command:

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -i

but still when I run the application I get this error :

```
Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive

<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
```

so what can I do to fix this?